# How to reverse last commit in git, when should use git checkout -f, or git restore <filename>

Tags: git, github-actions

when we are using git restore contact.html. than it is working for single file but when I use...
git restore -f
for restore all last modify file-back they throw the error like this ..
**error: unknown switch `f'
usage: git restore [] [--source=] ...**

Answer (score 1):

**`git restore -f` is wrong command.**

if you want to restore all  working tree files you can use:

```
git restore :/
```

with top pathspec magic.

Or more in general you can go to the root of the git project and do the command

```
git restore .
```

In this way you will restore al the files in the current folder, and if the folder is the root of the git repo, you will restore all the files.

Answer (score 1):

`git restore` is used to fetch a particular version of a file.

If you want to undo the latest commit with a new commit, you should use `git revert HEAD` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

If you want to just remove the commit from the history instead, you should use `git reset HEAD~ --hard` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Use `git-revert` if you are working with others and already pushed the commit you want to undo. Otherwise use `git reset` (followed by a force push if you pushed it to your remote)